# Android Google Maps release with other api key does not shows

Tags: android, google-maps, key

I have some issue that I have been searching without solution. I had have an app with Google Maps working well, but I deleted the project on console.developers.google.com by mistake, then the app stops to show the map.

I created another project on the console, I generated other api key with Google Maps for Android enabled. Then I changed my google_maps_api.xml value, I cleaned the project, then re-build and created a signed apk, but when install the app the maps not shows it.

I already tried this:

- Change to "None restriction" for the key and wait for 24 hours.
- I changed the XML attribute to templateMergeStrategy="replace".
- Shutdown and turn on my smartphone.
- Uninstall and install again my app.

  Nothings works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just declare your google map API key in the debug mode. There is one more google_map_api.xml file in the release folder. It should be like this, just copy/paste your api key.

[image]

P/s: Don't forget to switch your Build Variants to release before build signed apk

Comment: Thanks! It helps me